# Django lte and gte queries producing empty queryset

Tags: django-queryset

I'm stumped. I have a Django query that should return results, but does not seem to.

I have a database with a model Postcodes with latitude and longitude data.

```
class Postcode(models.Model):

name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
postcode = models.CharField(max_length=7)
latitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=5, blank=True, null=True)
longitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=5, blank=True, null=True)
```

I want to find the postcodes with 100km of a given postcode, at:

```
{'latitude': 1.445671659052796, 'longitude': 1.6673342919117797}
```

and I find the latitude and longitude ranges to be:

```
longitude_max = 1.9703812919117922
longitude_min = -1.3642872919117792
latitude_max = 52.2326886590528
latitude_min = 49.3413453409472
```

I query the db like so:

```
return Postcode.objects.filter(latitude__range=(latitude_min, latitude_max), longitude__range=(longitude_min, longitude_max))
```

But I don't get anything back? I should at least get the result I extrapolated the ranges from!

Answer (score 0):

If you are filtering with those parameters for that coordinate, the queryset will not contain that item.  The latitude is outside of the range provided.